# Neo4j unable to connect to graph database server

Tags: python, python-2.7, neo4j

I am using an example script to connect to the neo4j server and after that run a query. But I am getting this error:

> C:\cygwin\lib\python2.7\site-packages\neo4j\v1\session.py:94:
>   UserWarning: Bolt over TLS is only available in Python 2.7.9+ and
>   Python 3.3+ so communications are not secure
>
> warn("Bolt over TLS is only available in Python 2.7.9+ and Python
>   3.3+ "
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\FTS.fts-gnosis\workspace\hello1\tester.py", line 3, in
>   
>       session = driver.session()    File "C:\cygwin\lib\python2.7\site-packages\neo4j\v1\session.py", line 148,
>   in session
>       session = Session(self)    File "C:\cygwin\lib\python2.7\site-packages\neo4j\v1\session.py", line 461,
>   in **init**
>       self.connection = connect(driver.host, driver.port, driver.ssl_context, **driver.config)    File
>   "C:\cygwin\lib\python2.7\site-packages\neo4j\v1\connection.py", line
>   384, in connect
>       s = create_connection((host, port))    File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 553, in create_connection
>       for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
>
> socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed

Example code :

```
from neo4j.v1 import GraphDatabase, basic_auth
driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://http://localhost:7474",             auth=basic_auth("neo4j", "neo"))
session = driver.session()
result = session.run("MATCH (label:OFFICER)-[r]->()  WHERE label.NAME = 'Prinza Limited' RETURN label,r")
print result
session.close()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The driver only support Bolt, so no http possible.

Your connection uri mixes the two protocols, change to this :

```
driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://localhost",auth=basic_auth("neo4j", "neo"))
session = driver.session()
```

Normally, by just following the example in the repository readme, you shouldn't have the http in the connection uri :
https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-python-driver#example-usage

Comment: Silly mistake. sorry for the trouble

Comment: @ZohairZahid If this solved your issue, please accept the answer

Comment: when you hover the up and down arrows left to the answer, there should be a V appearing, click on it it should be green