# How to connect Python and neo4j?

Tags: python-2.7, neo4j, connection

I am new to `neo4j` and want it to connect with Python. I am using `neo4j` version 3.0.3 and following [this tutorial](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-python-driver).

I put the code below in my Python file, I have changed the password, since my password is `root`:

```
from neo4j.v1 import GraphDatabase, basic_auth
driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://localhost", auth=basic_auth(user = "neo4j", password = "root"))
session = driver.session()
session.run("CREATE (a:Person {name:'Bob'})")
result = session.run("MATCH (a:Person) RETURN a.name AS name")
for record in result:
    print(record["name"])
session.close()
```

But on running it, I am getting following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Work/MySQL_neo4j_Importer/dumping_ingredients.py", line 3, in <module>
    session = driver.session()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\neo4j\v1\session.py", line 148, in session
    session = Session(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\neo4j\v1\session.py", line 461, in __init__
    self.connection = connect(driver.host, driver.port, driver.ssl_context, **driver.config)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\neo4j\v1\connection.py", line 403, in connect
    s = create_connection((host, port))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 557, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed
```

I have also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37697695/neo4j-unable-to-connect-to-graph-database-server) StackOverFlow answer as well, but, the result remains same.

Answer (score 0):

For `Neo4j 1.8 / 1.9 / 2.0 / 2.1 / 2.2 / 2.3` you could use [Py2neo](http://py2neo.org/2.0/).

[Here](https://neo4j.com/developer/python/#neo4j-python-driver) you can find an exhaustive list of python drivers